# Exposing Quantlib and another library to C# via SWIG

Tags: c#, c++, swig, quantlib, quantlib-swig

Compiling and linking Quantlib takes some time, as it is not a small project. I am building some additional functionality on top of Quantlib, and I want to keep this additional functionality in a separate project.

Is there a way to easily expose two C++ projects into one library via SWIG? Because my project is quite small, just a few classes, I can easily afford to do manually what SWIG automates. However, I really want to deploy to my users only the bare minimum of files, that is the two dlls that are built by Quantlib-SWIG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Quantlib in particular, but generally, doing this with SWIG should be quite straightforward: the C# module of SWIG supports the `dllimport` option which allows you to specify the DLL referenced for the P/Invoke methods (refer to the C# section of the SWIG manual for details).

Thus, you can just create a separate SWIG interface file for your extension, set `dllimport` to the name used by Quantlib, and compile both C++ glue code files into a single DLL for both Quantlib and your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Resolver Systems'](http://www.resolversystems.com) pre-built binaries of [QuantLib with C# bindings](http://www.resolversystems.com/products/quantlib-binary/) although I am unsure how frequently they keep it up to date with QuantLib releases.

It will save you having to worry about one of your libraries at least?